# jQuery Form Validation for more fields

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using the following jQuery code for validating my form fields. But this code is only for 2 fields, and I have many more fields to go in my website. Is there a way to simplify this for more fields?

```
// Input validation
var wz_form1 = $('#wz_form1');
var wz_width = $('#wz_width');
var wz_height = $('#wz_height');

wz_width.blur(vld_wz_width);
wz_height.blur(vld_wz_height);

wz_form1.submit(function() {
    if(vld_wz_width() & vld_wz_height() ) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;   
    }
});

function vld_wz_width() {
    if(wz_width.val().length < 1) {
        wz_width.addClass('red_border');
        return false;
    } else{
        wz_width.removeClass('red_border');
        return true;

    }
}

function vld_wz_height() {
    if(wz_height.val().length < 1) {
        wz_height.addClass('red_border');
        return false;
    } else{
        wz_height.removeClass('red_border');
        return true;

    }
}
```

My last update:

```
var wz_form = $('#wz_form1');
$(wz_form).submit(function() {

    function wz_validation() {
        var txtboxes=$('input[validate="true"]');
        for(var i=0;i<txtboxes.length;i++) {

            if($(txtboxes[i]).val()=="") {
                $(txtboxes[i]).addClass('red_border');
                return false;
            }
            else{
                $(txtboxes[i]).removeClass('red_border');
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    if(wz_validation()) {
        return true;    
    }
    else{
        return false;   
    }

});
```

Comment: what type of validation is required?

Comment: Fields must not be empty, or is that not what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using type=text then you can use the following code

```
$(btnSubmit).click(function()
{
var txtboxes=$('input[type="text"]');
for(var i=0;i<txtboxes.length;i++)
{
if($(txtboxes[i]).val()=="")
$(txtboxes[i]).addClass('red_border');
else
$(txtboxes[i]).removeClass('red_border');
}
});
```

Comment: And how can I exclude some fields then? Working with a class?

Comment: add a custom attribute to the fields which you want to validate like '<input type="text" validate="true"/>' and change 'var txtboxes=$('input[type="text"]');' to 'var txtboxes=$('input[validate="true"]');' ... it will validate all the inputs that has attribute validate with value true.

Comment: Okay, can I also use the required property for this?

Comment: yes you can but the required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari. and you wont be able to add your css class if value is blank

Comment: Okay, so better use you validate true then.

Comment: I changed the btnSubmit to a form variable and .click to .submit because my form don't needs to be submit if the fields are not filled in but how can I do this with your script?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for the same and post the link?

Comment: the problem was in return statement. it was causing the for loop to end... here is the updated code. http://jsfiddle.net/6r3qt/1/

Comment: Thanks! Last thing: Know I define 1 form, but in one case I have 2 forms on one page. How can I define different / multiple forms?

Comment: you cannot have nested forms. so you can declare another form after closing form tag ie. </form> and if u want to use the same code then you will have to use $('form').each(function(){/*whole code here*/});

Answer (score 0):

If you require a Non blank validation you can use :

```
// Input validation
var wz_form1 = $('#wz_form1');
var wz_width = $('#wz_width');
var wz_height = $('#wz_height');
var wz_field1 = $('#wz_field1'); //Add new fields
var wz_field2 = $('#wz_field2');
//..... add all the required fields


wz_width.blur(vld_wz_width);
wz_height.blur(vld_wz_height);

wz_form1.submit(function() {
    if(vld_wz_width() & vld_wz_height() & vld_wz_field1 & vld_wz_field2 /* & so on ...*/ ) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;   
    }
});

function vld_wz_width() {
    if(wz_width.val().length < 1) {
        wz_width.addClass('red_border');
        return false;
    } else{
        wz_width.removeClass('red_border');
        return true;

    }
}

function vld_wz_height() {
    if(wz_height.val().length < 1) {
        wz_height.addClass('red_border');
        return false;
     } else{
        wz_height.removeClass('red_border');
        return true;

    }
}

 function vld_wz_fields() {
    if(wz_field1.val().length < 1) {
        wz_field1.addClass('red_border');
        return false;
     } else{
        wz_field1.removeClass('red_border');
        return true;

    }
}

 function vld_wz_fields() {
    if(wz_field2.val().length < 1) {
        wz_field2.addClass('red_border');
        return false;
     } else{
        wz_field2.removeClass('red_border');
        return true;

    }
}

//and so on ...
```

and if you're familiar with html5, you can only add `required` property on the form fields, this will do automatic form validation

Comment: Yeah so I do it normally, but I'm looking for a solution where I can make it simpler. Where I not need to add a function for each field but I think that's not possible right?

Comment: try adding `required` property.

Comment: Okay, and then you need to modify the script for all the required property fields right?

Comment: no only put `required` on the fields defentions,no scripts needed.
for examlpe `<input type="text" name="usrname" required>`
this should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your fields have ids that contain a common string like `_width`, you can use `ON()` like the following to attach validations:

```
$("input[id~='_width']").on("blur", vld_wz_width);
$("input[id~='_height'").on("blur", vld_wz_height);
```